# how to pass a variable with / as a parameter in javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have some path which is set to a variable

```
var imagepath = "../Resources/Images/teamLogo1.png";
```

Now on click of an image I have to pass this as a parameter in its onclick function

Please check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vEFWq/)

I am appending the image and i need to write onclick function there
EDIT:
Including the full code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var imagepath = "../Resources/Images/teamLogo1.png";
    $("#Testing").append('<img src="http://www.magerempowerment.com/v2/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/doubt_dice.jpg" onClick="testfunction('+ imagepath + ')">');

});

function testfunction(imagepath){
alert(imagepath);
};
```

Comment: Please copy the relevant code here; now one needs to see the fiddle to understand at all what you were asking.

Comment: okay added in the code ! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not embed handlers in HTML code at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imagepath = "../Resources/Images/teamLogo1.png",
        img = $('<img src="http://.../doubt_dice.jpg">');
    img.click(function () {
        // you can refer to imagepath here, for example
        $(this).prop('src', imagepath);

        // or call your function:
        testfunction.call(this, imagepath);
    });
    img.appendTo("#Testing");
});
```

Notice however that the relative paths (`"../Resources/Images/teamLogo1.png"`) are always relative to the HTML document.

Answer (score 2):

Since the value is a string, you need to enclose it with `''`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imagepath = "../Resources/Images/teamLogo1.png";
    $("#Testing").append('<img src="http://www.magerempowerment.com/v2/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/doubt_dice.jpg" onClick="testfunction(\'' + imagepath + '\')">');

});

function testfunction(imagepath) {
    alert(imagepath);
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AvZQN/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prop`

```
$('img').click(function(){
   alert($(this).prop('src')); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function will not call because you are creating `img dynamically` so try it like ,

**HTML**

```
$("#Testing").append('<img src="http://../doubt_dice.jpg" data-path="'+imagepath+'">');
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('click','img',function(){
    console.log($(this));
    alert($(this).data('path'));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vEFWq/2/)